# Permission mailbox subfolders

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have an Exchange (2010) mailbox that has 100+ folders. Each folder needs to be permissioned so that a certain AD security group has publishing editor rights. Is there a away to do mass permissioning or is it going to be a long day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Add-FolderPermissions Powershell cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298062.aspx) to set the permissions you need on each of your folders through Powershell. It offers no `-Recurse` option itself, but you could simply loop through Get-MailboxFolderStatistics' output to get all the folder names and feed them to Add-FolderPermissions as [described here](http://jimthemcp.blogspot.com/2010/09/set-outlook-folder-permissions-using.html):

```
ForEach($f in (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics John | Where { $_.FolderPath.Contains("/Clients") -eq $True } ) ) {
$fname = "John:" + $f.FolderPath.Replace("/","\");
Add-MailboxFolderPermission $fname -User Jane -AccessRights Reviewer
}
```